# Examples of "Monoidal Categories" without Pentagon Axiom

Tags: category-theory, monoidal-categories

One of the main goals of asserting the pentagon axiom for monoidal categories is to get the coherence theorem. I wondered how a typical example would look like that does not satisfy the theorem.

More concretely, I'm looking for a nice enough example of a "monoidal category" that has all the data of a monoidal category (as in e.g. [nLab](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/monoidal+category)) but does not satisfy the pentagon axiom. (I'd already be happy for an example that satisfies neither the pentagon nor the triangle axiom.)

One could probably just write down a small example by hand, though I'm not sure how typical such an example would be. I also found [arxiv:0109088](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0109088) but I'm admittingly a bit lazy to go through the author's example $\mathbf{IRBTree}$ which also looks a bit too complicated for my purposes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I asked this question on the German forum [MP/249861](https://matheplanet.com/matheplanet/nuke/html/viewtopic.php?topic=249861) and got a nice answer there.

Let e.g. $(\mathscr{C}, \otimes, \mathbf{1}, \lambda, \rho, \alpha)$ be a monoidal pre-additive category with left/right unitor $\lambda, \rho$ and associativity constraint $\alpha$. Then, $(\mathscr{C}, \otimes, \mathbf{1}, -\lambda, \rho, - \alpha)$ satisfies everything but the pentagon axiom.